# Switch case version of if(input.startsWith("string")) { ... } in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

**Context:** I am making a game that has a command handler. And inside that command Handler, i am trying to optimize a section of the code.

I am trying to make a switch-case statement that allows me to do the exact same thing as the one shown below

```
input.startsWith('echo') ? ( History.add(input), commands.echo(input) ) 
: ( input.startsWith('history') ? (History.add(input), commands.history(input))
: input.startsWith("new") ? (History.add(input), commands.new(input) ) 
: input.startsWith('theme') ? (History.add(input), commands.theme(input)) 
: (developerMode == true && input == "test") ? (History.add(input), commands.test()) 
: input.startsWith("cd") ? (History.add(input), commands.cd(input))
: input.startsWith("find") ? (History.add(input), commands.find(input, type, title)) 
: (History.add(input), utils.message({ user: '$', command: input }, ` - bash: ${input}: command not found `, 'error')))
```

**SIMPLIFIED VERSION:**

```
if (input.startsWith('echo')) {
    History.add(input)
    commands.echo(input);
} else if (input.startsWith("history"))
    History.add(input)
    commands.history(input);
} else if (input.startsWith("new")) {
    History.add(input)
    commands.new(input);
} else if (input.startsWith('theme')) {
    History.add(input)
    commands.theme(input);
} else if (developerMode == true && input == "test") {
    History.add(input)
    commands.test()
} else if (input.startsWith("cd")) {
    History.add(input)
    commands.cd(input)
} else if (input.startsWith("find")) {
    History.add(input)
    commands.find(input, type, title)
} else {
    History.add(input)
    utils.message({ user: '$', command: input }, ` - bash: ${input}: command not found `, 'error');
}
```

Comment: You don't want a switch/case statement - there is nothing inherantly wrong with the if statements (The ternary expression version is an abomination!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some redundency in your code. First, you can check if your command is a valid command by doing a test on `commands`'s keys (you should tryi to get the first command arguments without string#startWith).

As stated in a comment, you don't need to change a else-if to a switch. There is no gain. But, in both cases, you will have to add code to handle your commands, both to populate your command object AND to parse the user input.

To get some flexibility and reusability, the best you can do is to parse and execute all your commands in the same way.

Assuming that your commands are separated by whitespaces, there is a way to go :

```js
const [ cmd, ...args ] = input.split(' ');//at index 0, you get your command, in args, you get your command args. It's called array destructuring
//Note that you may need a more complexe way to parse your command, but you should get the idea.

//Since you do it every time, you don't have to repeat it
History.push(input);

if(cmd in commands) commands[cmd](input, ...args);
else utils.message(
    { user: '$', command: input }, 
    ` - bash: ${input}: command not found `, 'error'
);
```

Comment: Alr. You have literally helped me make a 60 liner switch-case (the rest that I didn't post) into a 5 liner. Thanks!

I have turned your If statement into a ternary to make it neater (i know. It has not effect on the performance at all. But i did cuz why not). Thanks!

Comment: Np ;) For the ternary syntax, do it as you want. Personaly, I use them only for conditional assignements (like `const defaultBehaviour = something === 'none' ? conf.something : 'default'` ) and NEVER to do else-if or switch satetments, because they are difficult to read, reason about and error-prone. But it depends of the scope of your project. If you're alone and that you find it readable, there is no problem.